# Correct way to implement a connection pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I'm trying to write a `multithreading program` that connects to a `MySQL database` and processes the returned set for a query (which has thousands of rows). The problem is that I have implemented the connection pool and I get every thread to open the connection to the database and get the resulting set. But I don't understand which is the advantage of using connection-pooling if retrieving that big set takes such a lot of time. It wouldn't be better if I get the whole set with only one connection (without using pooling) and then I use `thread pooling` to process it? Or is there a way that every thread takes the next row of the resulting set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a limited number of threads, I would have a connection per thread.

A connection pool is more efficient if the number of threads which could use a connection is too high and those thread use the connections a relatively low percentage of the time.

Comment: But my problem is that, once the thread gets the connection, I have to retrieve the whole set again, which takes a long time... Wouldn't be better to retrieve the whole set just once and then process it? I don't see the point of using connection-pooling.

Comment: I would get the whole set once and process it in one thread or using a thread pool. Using multiple connection only makes sense if they are doing different things.

Comment: ookay! no, they are doing the same thing. Now I get it! xD Thanks